# How to create a Google Maps API key with an API (not through the UI)?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-iam

Is there a way to programmatically create a Google Maps API key?
I googled this but couldn't find a straightforward answer.

[image]

Comment: @JohnHanley not quite true. Look into [gcloud beta services api-keys create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/services/api-keys/create). It's still in beta/alpha but it works just fine. BTW for each CLI/SDK operation, the corresponding REST/gRPC call is _usually_ available too. I couldn't find `create` but here's the [`list` command](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/operations/list). The docs may be outdated but I suppose it's worth a shot @AnandRockzz.

Comment: @Joe-GMapsBook.com - thank you very much. I don't know how I missed that release/announcement.

Comment: No worries! I don't know if it was announced but I found it by digging thru the docs. I had the same use case as the OP... I think the question should be reopened.

Comment: @Joe-GMapsBook.com Your comment sounds like an answer. Are you willing to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Nov 2023, you can programmatically create API keys with [Google Cloud's CLI (`gcloud`)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud).

You can use `gcloud` locally or as part of your CI/CD pipelines, e.g. in [Github Actions](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud).

Once you've got `gcloud` installed, authenticate and set the corresponding account + project:

```bash
gcloud config set account my@email.com
gcloud config set project my-project-name
```

After that, look into the [`services api-keys create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/services/api-keys/create) command. Right now it's only available in `beta/alpha` but it gets the job done:

```bash
gcloud beta services api-keys create \
  --display-name="Frontend API key - Prod" \
  --allowed-referrers="https://*.example.com/*" \
  --api-target=service=places.googleapis.com,service=maps.googleapis.com
```

To retrieve the list of available *services* (Maps and other GCP APIs) to pass in `--api-target`, run:

```bash
gcloud services list --available --filter="name:googleapis.com"
```

---

For each gcloud CLI operation, there's usually a REST call at your disposal. I couldn't find `create` but here are the docs for the [`list` command](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/operations/list). From this you can try to derive the `create` call - perhaps it's already implemented but not yet documented?

---

To learn more about API keys, read the [Google guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) or [this chapter of my Google Maps Handbook](https://gmapsbook.com/learn-google-maps/obtaining-your-maps-api-keys-5a82267e3f104f78a0357e5f641d1ef4).

Comment: Following did it! Thanks.

`cd ~/Downloads; wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-455.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz; tar -xvzf google-cloud-cli-455.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz; cd google-cloud-sdk; 
./install.sh; gcloud components install beta; gcloud config set account mymail@example.com; gcloud auth login; gcloud projects list --sort-by=projectId; gcloud config set project my-project-id; gcloud beta services api-keys list; `

Comment: Great - glad it worked!